# ScrollView nested in PagerView only allows you to scroll one at a time

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having an issue where I have a horizontal `PagerView` with a nested `ScrollView` where it scrolls both ways just fine, but I can't scroll on them at same time. On the  vertical `ScrollView` I have to wait till its lost all of its momentum and then it lets me Scroll. Anyone have any ideas on how do go about this?

**Example Code**

```js
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import PagerView from "react-native-pager-view";

const PagerWithScrollView = () => {
  return (
    <PagerView
      initialPage={currentItemIndex}
      onPageSelected={onPageSelected}
    >
      {items.map((page, i) => (
        <ScrollView key={page.id} className="flex px-4">
         {shouldRenderItem(i) ? <RenderItem index={i} /> : null}
        </ScrollView>
      ))}
    </PagerView>
  )
}
```